# Deploying smart contracts with truffle and geth in windows

Tags: truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

I'm trying to deploy a contract. When running: `truffle.cmd migrate network --ropsten` I get the following error:

> No network specified. Cannot determine current network.

Please help! Details are below

I've connected & unlocked my account in geth with:
`geth --fast --cache=1048 --testnet --unlock "mycontractaddress" --rpc --rpcapi "eth,net,web3" --rpccorsdomain '' --rpcaddr localhost --rpcport 8545` Previously, I have synced with the entire blockchain*

My truffle.js file is:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    localhost: {
       host: "localhost",
       port: 8545,
       network_id: "*"
    },
    ropsten: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "3"
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you try ``truffle.cmd migrate --network ropsten``?

Comment: @ivicaa can you add this as an answer? This post shows up in the review queue and as unanswered, and you're dead on the money that this is the right solution.

Comment: yes, that's the exact command I used. Please see the first paragraph of my question. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

`truffle.cmd migrate network --ropsten`

should be

`truffle.cmd migrate --network ropsten`

With `truffle.cmd networks` you can check which networks are available from your truffle.js.

Comment: That solved one of the problems for sure, thanks! Still can't deploy. I get the following error:


Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Deploying Migrations...
  ... undefined
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: exceeds block gas limit
at Object.InvalidResponse (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\~\web3\lib\web3\errors.js:38:1)

Comment: I also created a new migrations file for the contract I'm trying to deploy using the same format as the 1_initial_migration contract that was auto created. I wrote the following code:
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};

Comment: Try to add the "gas" property to your truffle.js. Something with 5000000 or more. It seems like the default value for the gas limit is not high enough.

Comment: I did and now I'm getting a syntax error about gas. Is this the correct truffle.js syntax? Also, do I need to include the development network in the code?
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    localhost: {
      host: "localhost", 
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" 
   gas: 500000
   }
    ropsten: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "3"
   gas: 500000
    }
  }
}

Comment: You‘re missing a comma in front of gas and also one more 0. Should be 5Mil.

Comment: module.exports = {
  networks: {
    localhost: {
      host: "localhost", 
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" 
   gas: 5000000,
   }
    ropsten: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "3"
   gas: 5000000,
    }
  }
}

Comment: I'm still getting the same syntax error about gas (see my updated truffle.js file above)
    gas: 5000000,
          ^^^

Comment: module.exports = { networks: { localhost: { host: "localhost", port: 8545, network_id: "*", gas: 5000000 } ropsten: { host: "localhost", port: 8545, network_id: "3", gas: 5000000 } } }       ---- spot the difference. ;-)